# no changes in my php page

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I do not understand why nothing changes in my php page when I make changes in my drop down menu.

This is the page where I test it.

http://php.aryapratinidhisabha.org.uk/excercise4.php

please see the code here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<table>
<tr>
<td> <label for=”font”> Select Font: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”font” name=”font”>
<option value=”Verdana”> Verdana </option>
<option value=”Arial”> Arial </option>
<option value=”Times New Roman”> Times New Roman </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td> <label for=”size”> Select Size: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”size” name=”size”>
<option value=”10px”> 10px </option>
<option value=”12px”> 12px </option>
<option value=”16px”> 16px </option>
<option value=”20px”> 20px </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td> <label for=”color”> Select Color: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”size” name=”size”>
<option value=”black”> black </option>
<option value=”green”> green </option>
<option value=”purple”> purple </option>
<option value=”red”> red </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</form>

$_SESSION['font']=$_POST['font'];
$_SESSION['size']=$_POST['size'];
$_SESSION['color']=$_POST['color'];


<p <?php
echo ' style=”font-family: ' . $_SESSION['font'] . '; ';
echo 'font-size: ' . $_SESSION['size'] . '; ';
echo 'color: ' . $_SESSION['color']. ';" ';
?>> Text to display </p>
```

Comment: How does your javascript look?

Comment: Hi leo, there is no Javascript. :)

Comment: Your code contains irregular `”` quotes which will cause a 500 error. Change those to regular quotes `"`. Plus, your code in the link doesn't contain an opening `<form>` tag. Unsure what you want to achieve without seeing the rest of your code; **if** there is more code. Since you are using sessions, I don't see where you started the session. Your question is unclear. Changes do not happen on their own; not without Javascript.

Comment: Fred ii,you are right. I made those changes and inlcuded more code.
$_SESSION['font']=$_POST['font'];
$_SESSION['size']=$_POST['size'];
$_SESSION['color']=$_POST['color']; Pleas see the link now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, if you are not going to use jQuery or javascript, you will need to *submit* your form with a button or input type=submit

e.g.:

```
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Also, php code that your placing *within* the html needs to be placed between php tags:

```
<html>
...
<?php
// php code here
?>
```

(specifically talking about the: `$_SESSION` globals).

Additionally, as was brought up in the comments on your question, you are going to need `<form>` and also to tell it where the form is submitting to.

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
```

The method can also be `get` and you can also submit to the same page by leaving `action=""` blank. Up to you.

Comment: Mikolaj, This is very much appreciated. Thanks. It is now working. However, the colours are not working and the size is not working either. Any ideas! Tanks again1

Comment: @NaveenGanpat Looks like you are placing the variables in the wrong places. When I ran it, it put purple inside the `font-size:`...